# Angular 8 Library: Modules not found after installing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

We are in the process of upgrading our repos from Angular 7 to Angular 8 (and eventually to 9). We have an Angular library repo that was just upgraded to a proper Angular 8 Library and everything seems to be working fine there and is published as a private NPM package. Our primary Angular 8 app consumes the library, but I am getting module errors for everything in the library:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@my-scope/my-library/a-z-list-legend' in '[local-path]/src/app'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@my-scope/my-library/analytics' in '[local-path]/src/app'
and so on...
```

I followed the [Angular - Creating libraries](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries) guide, so I'm using the command: `ng build my-library` and publish to NPM. I get no errors there.

Here is a screenshot of the file structure of my library:
[image]

Just as a note, I am still using barrels that are referenced in my `public-api.ts` file.

This is what gets installed in `node_modules`, along with each of the ES version bundles:
[image]

And example module import in `app.module.ts` looks like this:

```ts
import { AZListLegendModule } from '@my-scope/my-library/a-z-list-legend';
```

At this point I'm at a bit of a loss and I'm not sure if it's a problem with the library or the consuming app. Thank you for any assistance.

UPDATE:
Here is an abbreviated `package.json` used in both repos:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.802.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

And `ng --version` dump:

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 8.2.2
Node: 10.17.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.802.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.802.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.802.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.802.2
@angular-devkit/core               8.2.2
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.2.2
@angular/cdk                       8.2.3
@angular/cli                       8.2.2
@angular/flex-layout               8.0.0-beta.27
@angular/material                  8.2.3
@angular/material-moment-adapter   8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                   8.2.2
@schematics/angular                8.2.2
@schematics/update                 0.802.2
rxjs                               6.4.0
typescript                         3.5.3
webpack                            4.38.0
```

UPDATE 2:
It looks like Angular 8 Libraries do not support deep imports. Changing all of my imports to just `@my-scope/my-library` seems to work.

Comment: can you provide "ng --version" for project and libs?

Comment: Updated with package versions.